# Solution of trigonometric equation $0 = x\cos(x)+2$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry, exponential-function, maxima-minima

I'm having a hard time finding the solution of the following equation:

$$0 = x\cos(x)+2$$

This is part of showing that $f(x):= x^2e^{\sin(x)}$ has 3 extremas in $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$.

Comment: Do you need to _find_ the solutions, or show that solutions _exist_?

Comment: Show that they exist and of which kind they are (minimum/maximum)

Comment: Solutions to $0 = x\cos(x) + 2$ aren't maxima or minima. At any rate, finding the solutions is _really hard_. Showing that they exist is pretty easy, if you know the right theorem. And my guess is that you actually know the right theorem.

Comment: They just are what?

Comment: I would try thm. of rolle I guess

Comment: I'm a bit confused now when I look at the graph of $f$ there is only one extremum at all

Comment: Hint: Look for solutions $x_k$ close to $(k+\frac{1}{2})\pi$ for $k=0,\pm 1,\pm 2,...$

Answer (score 2):

If:

$$y(x)=x^2 e^{\sin x}$$

then:

$$y'=xe^{\sin x}(x\cos x + 2)$$

Now if you put $y'=0$ we have:

$$xe^{\sin x}(x\cos x + 2)=0$$

Note that $e^{\sin x}$ > 0 so we get:

$$x(x\cos x +2)=0$$

...which means that:

$$x = 0 \ \ \lor \ \ (x \cos x +2) =0$$

For all values in the interval $x\in [0,\pi/2]$ obviously $x\cos x+2>0.$

For $x\in[-\pi/2, 0)$, $|x \cos x| \le|x|<\pi/2 < 2$ so in this interval we aslo have $x\cos x+2>0.$

This leaves us with only one possibility for an extremal value  in $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ and that is $x=0$.

The plot of $y(x)$ just confirms that you cannot have 3 extremas in the specified interval:

[image]